# Disable <Option-u>, <Option-n> accent mark

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I know this has to do with my keyboard layout being U.S, but I have no idea what to do from here. I'm using MacVim, so I want to bind `<Alt-u>` to something, but I realized it was waiting for another character, and sure enough if you type `<Alt-u>` you can get characters like this: ï  if you type another character after it. I want to disable this behavior and I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution, which is to download [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and then create a new US keyboard from your current (or whatever language you are reading this in), and then modify the dead keys to whatever you want. I made https://github.com/norcalli/undead-us-keyboard as result of this with a keyboard layout already made and installation instructions.